# Reports on opportunities historical value

Tags: reporting, opportunity, dashboard, analytic-snapshots

I am working for a customer that has very specific requirements regarding reports and dashboard and would love to know how you would tackle the following :

The customer requires a column graph (vertical bar) where the x-axis represents dates grouped by month, and the y-axis represents the Opportunity.amount (renamed Expected Value in our org). Each bar on the graph should represent the snapshot of the Opportunity Amount on the last day of each month. This snapshot value remains fixed after the end of the respective month, as any changes to the opportunity amount after the last day of the month will be reflected in the next month's bar. This snapshot should be generated at the end of each month.

Additionally, there's a need to incorporate a snapshot of the Opportunity.Expectedrevenue (renamed Weighted Value in this org (amount * probability)) on the same graph, preferably as a Stacked Column. Similar to the opportunity amount, this snapshot should be taken on the last day of each month and remain fixed thereafter.

The objective is to visualize the evolution of the sales pipeline per month over time, considering both the opportunity amount and the opportunity expected revenue (amount * probability).

Reporting snapshot wouldnt work because they want to see it in graph, also i have enabled historical trending but there a few limitations such as :

- cannot group multiple value on the X-axis (both amount to be displayed
- cannot have the history on formula fields
- cannot use bucket field

How would you tackle this?

Thanks in advance for your help,

KL

Comment: You compute the necessary values at the end of the month/whenever, write it out to the custom object and do your report from there.

Comment: It's been a while since I used reporting snapshots but I don't recall that you couldn't do charts on them - they are objects like any other

Comment: @cropredy In many cases (and possibly this one) snapshots fall short because the report is the data source